# Cloud function deploy error in move class in different file

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am newbie in TypeScript and firebase.

This code is call firebase cloud function: testPromise to get FirestoreDoc through Promise.
I wrote some code on below.

**index.ts**

```ts
class FirestoreDoc
{
    static readonly DEFAULT_DOC_VER         = 1;
    static readonly FIELD_DOC_VER           = "docVer";
    docVer:number = 1;

    static readonly DEFAULT_CREATE_TIME     = -1;
    static readonly FIELD_CREATE_TIME       = "createTime";
    createTime:number = -1;
}

function getDoc() : Promise<FirestoreDoc>
{
    let someCondition = true;
    let myDoc = new FirestoreDoc();
    return new Promise<FirestoreDoc> ((resolve, reject)=> {
        if(someCondition)
            resolve(myDoc);
        else
            reject("false on condition");
    });
}

export const testPromise = functions
    .https.onRequest(async (request, response) => 
{
    await getDoc()
    .then((doc:FirestoreDoc)=>{
        console.log("success doc.docVer:" + doc.docVer);
    })
    .catch(()=>{
        console.log("false");
    })
    response.send("testPromise response");
});
```

and deploy it. That is OK, it works fine.

Then I move class FirestoreDoc and function getDoc() to Database.ts file, and modify my code to below:

**Database.ts**

```ts
export class FirestoreDoc
{
    static readonly DEFAULT_DOC_VER         = 1;
    static readonly FIELD_DOC_VER           = "docVer";
    docVer:number = FirestoreDoc.DEFAULT_DOC_VER;

    static readonly DEFAULT_CREATE_TIME     = -1;
    static readonly FIELD_CREATE_TIME       = "createTime";
    createTime:number = FirestoreDoc.DEFAULT_CREATE_TIME;
}

export function getDoc() : Promise<FirestoreDoc>
{
    let someCondition = true;
    let myDoc = new FirestoreDoc();
    return new Promise<FirestoreDoc> ((resolve, reject)=> {
        if(someCondition)
            resolve(myDoc);
        else
            reject("false on condition");
    });
}
```

**indes.ts**

```ts
import * as Database from "./Database/Database";

export const testPromise = functions
    .https.onRequest(async (request, response) =>
{
    await Database.getDoc()
    .then((doc:Database.FirestoreDoc)=>{
        console.log("success doc.docVer:" + doc.docVer);
    })
    .catch(()=>{
        console.log("false");
    })
    response.send("testPromise response");
});
```

It pass the build process, but fail on deploy.
[Deploy Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iM1e.jpg)

What is the problem?

**UPDATE**

I found the bug.
[Logging on GCP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34T26.jpg)

It shows on found Database.ts module.
So I back to [my local folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezWjd.jpg) and found what wrong. The folder name is database. I refactor the source TypeScript folder name but do not refactor this.
So I delete this folder and rebuild it, it works.

Thank you very much, Muthu Thavamani.

Comment: could you update the error logs? check the firebase function logs panel as mentioned in your deploy log.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug. Logging on GCP

It shows on found Database.ts module. So I back to my local folder and found what wrong. The folder name is database. I refactor the source TypeScript folder name but do not refactor this. So I delete this folder and rebuild it, it works.

Thank you very much, Muthu Thavamani.